# In CRM 2011 how to create a record and associate it in the same ExecuteMultipleRequest

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm struggling to find a way to use the ExecuteMultipleRequest to create a record and associate it to other records at the same time.  So far I've only been successful in first creating the record, and then in another request set up my associations.

With this code it throws an exception that it requires a target (Which would need to have previously been submitted to create the record and get an ID)

```
private AssociateRequest GetConfigurationRequest(VariableDataRequestModel receivedRequest)
{
    var configurationRelationship = new Relationship(ConfigurationRelationshipName);            
    var configurationEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection(new EntityReference[]{new EntityReference(ConfigurationEntityLogicalName,new Guid(receivedRequest.ConfigurationId))});                        
    var rtn = new AssociateRequest() {  RelatedEntities = configurationEntities, Relationship = configurationRelationship };
    return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to achieve with `ExecuteMultipleRequest` is to specify the `Id` of the new record before you create the record:

```
Guid accountId = new Guid("c85dca5d-6520-4436-a5f6-178b633af819");

Entity myAccount = new Entity("account");
myAccount["name"] = "TEST ACCOUNT";
entity.Id = accountId;
// ...
EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection();
relatedEntities.Add(new EntityReference("account", accountId));
```

Specify the `Id` is permitted but not suggested.

Comment: Letting the platform create sequential Guids allows for better SQL performance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2015/01/19/the-dangers-of-guid-newguid.aspx

Comment: That's unfortunate. I really try to use ExecuteMultipleRequest as often as possible for performance improvement.  It sounds like I'd just be trading some short term performance for long term performance issues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is to submit the record in an ExecuteMultipleRequest and then get the GUID in the ExecuteMultipleResponse, then you can use that GUID with your created Record to do the AssociateRequest.

Example:

```
ExecuteMultipleResponse response = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(updateCRM);

List<Entity> addedRecordList = new List<Entity>();

foreach (ExecuteMultipleResponseItem item in response.Responses)
{
    Guid responseReturnedGuid = (Guid)item.Response.Results.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x is Guid);
    if (responseReturnedGuid != Guid.Empty || responseReturnedGuid != null)
    {
        Entity addedRecord = (Entity)updateCRM.Requests[item.RequestIndex].Parameters.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x is Entity);
        addedRecord.Id = responseReturnedGuid;
        addedRecordList.Add(addedRecord);
    }
}
```